# duplicate content in an environment

Tags: environments

I am trying to define a (new) environment, say "exercise", with an optional argument, and a command \repeat, that work in the following way:

First I write an exercise in the document:

```
\begin{exercise}{hello}
bla bla
\end{exercise}
```

Then later in the document I want to repeat this exercise:

```
\repeat{hello}
```

Clearly, the output should reproduce the exercise. I am actually able to do that with standard commands (see the code below), but I would really like it to be an actual environment to work well with the option+click feature that brings me to the exact place where I've clicked.

Code that works but not in a satisfactory way:

```
 \newcommand\exercise[2]{%
\expandafter\gdef\csname exercise#1\endcsname{#2}%
\label{#1}#2}
\newcommand\repeat[1]{\csname exercise#1\endcsname}
```

Comment: With _option+click_ you mean the synchronization between your code editor window and the pdf preview window? Which editor and operating system do you use? Also, which behavior do you want exactly - when you click on a repeated exercise in the pdf you go the the original definition in the LaTeX code? Or when you click on a repeated exercise you go to the `\repeat` command in the LaTeX code? The first option would be difficult, but maybe not impossible. Which behavior do you get now, where do you click and where does the editor go?

Comment: yes I mean this sync feature. I use texshop on mac. Right now if I click on the duplicate i go to the \repeat command, and if I click on the original I arrive at then end of the exercice, which is not very convenient if it is a long exercise with corrections, etc... I would at least like that if I click on the original exercise, it behaves nicely, usually it is the case when you use proper environments. If in addition clicking in the duplicate exercise would bring me to the original latex code, it would be super!

Comment: It’s not how SyncTeX works. You can use a hyperlink that sends you to the original exercise and then click for the code.

Comment: Ok thanks. And for repeating the content of the environment, you have an idea?